# Extruding edges on the plane

Tags: extrude

When I extrude my edges, they extrude at an angle. I'm trying to make the clothing pattern for a dress, so all the vertices should be on one plane. I'm working on the neckline now (see image). I want to extrude the edges towards the centre and on one plane. But each time I toggle from front view to left view, I see that I extruded the edges at an angle (see image). This was obviously not my intention. Any advice on how how to achieve the desired result?

[image: front view and side view]

Comment: As this is 3-dimensional space, extruding can happen in all 3 axes at the same time, I don't see anything unexpected. It is a good modeling workflow to always either have 3 orthographic views opened next to your main one in order to check how geometry is aligned or constantly rotate the view. [Edit] the question with information how you extruded, what is unexpected and how do you want it. So far the question isn't quite clear. (Also please write more descriptive titles)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to work entirely on the X-Z plane, like here (note the little axes on the bottom left):

[image]

then, every time you extrude, make sure to do <kbd>E</kbd>, **then <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Y</kbd>**: this will exclude the Y axis from the extrusion. This works even if you are not in front view.

[image]

---

To fix a mesh that was mistakenly extruded along the Y axis, do <kbd>A</kbd>(<kbd>A</kbd>)<kbd>S</kbd><kbd>Y</kbd><kbd>0</kbd>

[image]

- <kbd>A</kbd>: select all (twice if something was already selected)
- <kbd>S</kbd>: scale ...
- <kbd>Y</kbd>: ... along the Y axis ...
- <kbd>0</kbd> ("zero"): ... until its width is 0% of the original